# How to execute a program using wildcards in the path

Tags: windows, batch-file

I try to launch an .exe file in a very simple batch script.

The problem I'm faced in is that I don't know the name of the target folder where the program is located cause it's suffixed by the version number.

I've already tried various ways using wildcards but that don't seems to works.

I mean, if I `cd` into a path it works but not when I want to start a program.

Working example:

```
cd C:\my-program-folder-*.*.*
```

Failing example:

```
C:\my-program-folder-*.*.*\prog.exe
```

Comment: What is the actual full path?

Comment: The actual full-path is `C:\test-1.2.3\GPU-Z.exe`

Comment: Your `launch.bat` is as simple as `start C:\test-1.2.3\GPU-Z.exe`. Works for me, if your results are different than the application launching, can you post the error you receive?

Comment: Since it's a batch file already, why not just `CD` into the folder using the wildcards first, and then just launch `prog.exe`, without specifying the path?  BTW: `cd c:\my-program-folder-*` should be enough, no need for the extra `.*.*`, as there are no 'extensions' on folder names (just names with dots in them)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Big thanks! It's so evident, I don't know why I don't try this way before.

Comment: @root I can't do like you said cause the version number can vary at any time. Again thanks to you guys.

Comment: No problem, @DavidPostill <strike>stole</strike> has the answer and posted it, so go give him the checkmark (he needs them or his body will start to turn into fragrant goo). ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Lol. Did not steal. Was writing answer without reading all the comments. ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill I know, I'm just screwing with ya. ;)

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I execute a program using wildcards in the path

> Working example:
>
> ```
> cd C:\my-program-folder-*.*.*
> ```
>
> Failing example:
>
> ```
> C:\my-program-folder-*.*.*\prog.exe
> ```

You can use:

```
cd C:\test-* && GPU-Z.exe
```

Note:

- `&&` - if the previous command (`cd C:\test-*`) succeeds then run the next command (`GPU-Z.exe`)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.

Comment: Note that this will fail if there are multiple matching directories and the first match isn't the one you need.

Answer (score 3):

This another approch :

For example i don't know the location of the folder that contains this file **vbc.exe** : ***The Visual Basic compiler***.

So, i can do like this :

```
@echo off
Title To find the last version of .NET Framework Compilateur vbc.exe and execute it in command line
color 0b
for /F %%i in ('dir /B /S ^"%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\*vbc.exe^"') do set vbc=%%i
if /i "%vbc%"=="" cls & color 1c & echo You don't have any version of .NET Framework Compilateur vbc.exe & pause & exit
echo The last version of .NET Framework Compilateur vbc.exe is located at this path :
echo. 
echo %vbc%
echo.
echo Press any key to run it !
pause>nul
cls
cmd /k %vbc%
pause
```